# Show that $p(n, m)=\frac{m-1}{m} \times \cdots \times \frac{m-n+1}{m} \le (e^{\frac{-n}{2m}})^{n-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $p(n, m) \le e^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2m}}$. It's also given that $p(n,m)= \frac{m-1}{m} \times \cdots \times \frac{m-n+1}{m}$.

It's also given that $n$ is odd, so $(n-1)/2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

So we will try to find an upper bound:

$$(m-1) \times \cdots \times ( m-n+1) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)$$

This can be bounded as,

\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k) &= \prod_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(m-j) \times (m-n+j) \tag{1}\label{tag1}\\
&\vdots\\
&\le \prod_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(m-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2 \\&= \left(\left(m-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \\&= \left(m-\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n-1} 
\end{align}

We can conclude that,

$$p(n,m) \le \left(\frac{m-\frac{n}{2}}{m}\right)^{n-1} = \left(1-\frac{n}{2m}\right)^{n-1} $$
$$\left(1-\frac{n}{2m}\right)^{n-1}  \le (e^{\frac{-n}{2m}})^{n-1} \tag{2}\label{tag2}\\$$

**Problems**:

1. Can you please show how \ref{tag1} changed bound of product to $\frac{n-1}{2}$ and how we got terms inside $(m-j)(m-n+j)$ please?
2. Can you please show how \ref{tag2} got upper bound $e^{\frac{-n}{2m}} $ for $\left(1-\frac{n}{2m}\right)$?

Comment: What is $n1$ in the exponential?

Comment: @Gary. Thanks. I am not sure where this is $n1$? I have $e^{\frac{-n}{2m}}$ in the exponential

Comment: Look at the title and the first line.

Comment: @Gary. Oh! That was a mistake. I edited it thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: It looks like the inequality should be $$p(n,m)\leq e^{-n(n-1)/(2m)}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Thank you. Yes.

Comment: In $(1)$ you don't have $k$ but $j$ in the RHS.

Comment: @VIVID. Yes. Thanks Corrected.

Comment: One weakness in the proof is the assumption that $m$ is odd, so we can pair up the terms. A workaround is now in and edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is mostly fine.

There is a problem that your proof assumes $p(m,n)$ has an even number of terms. The combining of terms in $(1)$ is only true when $n$ is odd.

It is easier to prove, when using this method, that $$p^2(m,n)\leq e^{n(n-1)/m}$$

Then $$\begin{align} 
m^{2(n-1)}p^2(m,n)&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)\right)^2\\
&= \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)\right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-n+k)\right)
\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)(m-n+k)
\end{align} 
$$
and then use the AM/GM on these terms, as in your posted proof. The second equality is because $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}f(n-k)$$

The last step, $(2)$ in your proof, is because $0<1+x\leq e^x,$ where $x=-\frac{n}{2m}.$

---

An easier proof uses [Bernoulli’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality): $$1+kx\leq (1+x)^k, x\geq -1, k\in \mathbb N$$
and the related inequality:
$$1+x\leq e^x, x\in \mathbb R.\tag3$$

We assume $n\leq m.$ If $n>m,$ the inequality is true because $p(m,n)=0.$

For $1\leq k<m,$ Bernoulli shows, for $x=-\frac 1m$:

$$0<1-\frac km\leq \left(1-\frac1m\right)^k$$

So:

$$\begin{align} 
p(m,n)&=\left(1-\frac1m\right) \left(1-\frac2m\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{n-1}m\right)\\
&\leq \left(1-\frac1m\right)^{1+2+\cdots+(n-1)}\\
&= \left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n(n-1)/2}
\end{align}$$

Finally, by $(3)$ for $x=-\frac1m,$ we have:

$$1-\frac1m\leq e^{-1/m}.$$

So: $$p(n,m)\leq e^{\frac{-n(n-1)}{2m}}$$

---

Bernoulli can be used to prove $(3)$ since Bernoulli shows that: $$1+x\leq \left(1+\frac xk\right)^k$$ for $k>|x|.$ So:$$1+x\leq \lim_{k\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xk\right)^k=e^x$$

Comment: Second question please, what you meant by "then use the AM/GM on these terms."

Comment: Do what was done in the proof in your question. $$(m-k)(m-n+k)\leq (m-n/2)^2$$ That step is due to the Arithmetic Mean/Geometric Mean Inequality, commonly referred to as “AM/GM.” @Avra

Comment: You answer is very clear and more straight forward, but again I am just not able to get please how you get $ \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-n+k)\right)$ in $\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)\right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-n+k)\right)$

Comment: A change of variables means $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} f(n-k)$$ This is just reversing the order of the product. If $f(k)=m-k,$ then $f(n-k)=m-n+k.$ @Avra

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Can you give me a resource for this change of variables please so that I can further read about it like proof? It's like instead of finding from product from first to last, you are finding it from last to first?

Comment: There is no resource. It is the same as writing $$f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n-2)f(n-1)=f(n-1)f(n-2)\cdots f(2)f(1)$$ @Avra It’s just repeated application of the commutative and associative laws of multiplication.

Comment: 100% clear. Thank you very much.